# Deleting CKRecord from Cloudkit in swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, cloudkit, ckrecord

I am trying to have the users' location be updated by this function. Originally it was saving the users' location every time, but I added the code that will be below the comment. How can I make sure the record that is being deleted is the old location?

```
let locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations.last
        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()//
        locationRecord.setObject(location, forKey: "location")
        let publicData = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
        publicData.saveRecord(locationRecord) { record, error in
        }
            if error == nil
            {
                print("Location saved")
                self.loc1 = location!
            }
        //testing code below
        let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: nil, recordIDsToDelete: [locationRecord.recordID])
        operation.savePolicy = .AllKeys
        operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { added, deleted, error in
            if error != nil {
                print(error)
            } else {
                print("location updated")
            }
        }
        CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase.addOperation(operation)
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to add a new CKRecord and delete the old one, rather than just keeping one and updating it?

Comment: How would I modify the existing one? @michael

Comment: By keeping a local reference to the existing one - possibly in NSUserDefaults. If it doesn't exist, you know you need to save for the first time, Otherwise you need to fetch the existing record, update it, and then save it back. Have a look under "Fetching an Existing Record" in the doco - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to update the existing one, as @Michael pointed out.  The easy way to do this would be the first time you create the record, save the recordID to the defaults.  For example,

```
func getRecordToUpdate(locations:[CLLocation])->CKRecord?{
  let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
  var locationRecord:CKRecord

  if defaults.objectForKey("locationRecordID") == nil{
      //Create a new record and save its id
      locationRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "location")
      defaults.setObject(locationRecord.recordID, forKey: "locationRecordID")
      self.updateLocationRecord(locationRecord, locations)
  }else{
      //Fetch the already existing record
      let publicDB = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
      publicDB.fetchRecordWithID((defaults.objectForKey("locationRecordID") as! CKRecordID), completionHandler{
          (record, error) in
          if error == nil{
            self.updateLocationRecord(record, locations)
          }else{
            print("Error fetching previous record")
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Create a new function,

```
func updateLocationRecord(locationRecord:CKRecord, locations:[CLLocation]){
   //Put your code from "let location..." to just above the testing code
   //You may want to fix the block syntax in the call to saveRecord
}
```

Then in the original locationManager method, take out everything and put

```
self.getRecordsToUpdate(locations)
```

Comment: I am getting an error on "updateRecord" where did you define that @milesper

Comment: Sorry, updateRecord is the function where you put the code that stores and saves the location information like you have abovd

Comment: Where are you suggesting I put this code? Should it still include the delete part in updateRecord ? @milesper

Comment: Actually you may want to put the code I wrote in a function that returns a ckrecord to where you had it before. I can explain more later if you need.

Comment: That would be very helpful thanks. I'm new to servers. @milesper

Comment: I'll have it in a few hours

Comment: thank you. ill give you the bounty tomorrow when it lets me. @milesper

Comment: I get a thread 1 breakpoint at on the line that says "defaults.setObject(locationRecord.recordID, forKey: "locationRecordID")" with the reason being "Attempt to set a non-property-list object <CKRecordID: 0x12d713450; 791943E5-FAC7-413F-A971-F4AC37E96115:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__)> as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key locationRecordID"

Comment: @Caleb in that case I would make some field in the record type like "user" and then instead of storing the record I'd, storing the username and using a CKQuery to get the appropriate object